# How can I synchronize over Java aspects defined around a method?

Tags: java, synchronization, aspectj

I have a Hibernate transactional method "doImportImpl" which runs multi-threaded. Certain records however need to be imported in sequence, so the code structure is roughly like this:

```
public RecordResult doImportImpl(String data) {
    RecordResult result = new RecordResult();
    .. do some data processing ..
    String recordIdentifier = getIdentifier(data);
    synchronized(recordIdentifier) {
       process record;
    }
    return result;
}
```

There is a different transaction method which also has the record identifier and cannot run in parallel to the record import. It therefore is also synchronized on 'record identifier'.

```
public void autoProcess(String data) {
    String recordIdentifier = getIdentifier(data);
    synchronized(recordIdentifier) {
       List<Record> records = dao.queryDatabase(recordIdentifier);
       for (Record r : records) {
           autoprocess record;
       }
    }
}
```

Here's the problem: it seems that sometimes that the method `autoProcess()` starts to run AFTER the synchronized block from `doImportImpl()` is finished, but BEFORE the transaction is committed. So, due to tx isolation level, the call to `dao.queryDatabase()` does not yet see the imported records on the database.

How do I make sure the synchronized lock is held all the way through the "return statement" including all aspects around the method call (which handle Hibernate transaction management)? Is it sufficient to put the return statement into the synchronized block?

Thanks
Simon Niederberger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use database locks instead of `synchronized` blocks. When you query a record by the `recordIdentifier` use `select for update` or what's available for your database.

Also, for me it's smells to synchronize on a `String`s.

Comment: Thanks for the hint reg. synchronizing on Strings. I thought I had understood the implications, but was proven wrong after reading up some more on the topic. I'll change that part, but regardless of that the main question still stands. I'm reluctant to "select for update", as that will probably impact DB performance quite a bit. 98% of the time there is no concurrent processing of data with the same record identifier, so the code should be optimized for that case.